# How can I create a thick border on the right hand side of the first <td> in my rows?

Tags: css

How can I create a thick right-hand side border on the first `<td>` of each row only:

```
<table class="code">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>01</td><td></td>
      </tr>    
      <tr>
         <td>02</td><td>interface Transport {}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/CCgME/)

and here's the code

```
.code tr td:first-child {
    border-right:5px solid red;
}​
```

oh well, too late.

Comment: Never too late. +1. Plus you provided a demo as well detailed selector.

Comment: +1 for being the 1 in 4 who also writes something for the human, not just for the machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
td:first-child {
   border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
td:first-child
{
 border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td:first-of-type {
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```